# SVM model keeps predicting the same probabilities for every input data

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have trained two models, Random Forest (RF) and Support Vector Machine (SVM), on a large dataset of 3000 images for a binary classification. I saved these models as `.pkl` and then I loaded them so that I obtain prediction for some test images which I successively upload in my app.

RF model works fine, but my application UI (and my terminal) keeps showing me the same probability values over and over again for SVM, even though it is almost the same code for both models.

```
with open('app/saved_models/svm_model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        svm_model = pickle.load(file)

image = cv2.imread('app/uploads/' + filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Processing
processed_image = preprocessing.clahe.get_CLAHE(image)
features = feature_extraction.get_GLCM.extract_GLCM_single(processed_image)

# Reshaping the features to match the input shape
reshaped_features = features.reshape(1, -1)

#Predicting the class probabilities 
class_probabilities = svm_model.predict_proba(reshaped_features)
predicted_class = svm_model.classes_[np.argmax(class_probabilities)]
benign_prob = class_probabilities[0, 0]
malignant_prob = class_probabilities[0, 1]

# response dictionary
response = {
    'predicted_class': predicted_class,
    'benign_probability': benign_prob,
    'malignant_probability': malignant_prob
}
```

In my JS code, I just print the probabilities on UI, on a click listener.

```
predictBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const selectedAlgorithm = algorithmSelect.value;
  const selectedConfigurationSVM = customDropdownSVM.value;
  const filename = predictBtn.dataset.filename;
  let parameters;
  if (selectedAlgorithm === 'svm') {
    parameters = {
      algorithm: selectedAlgorithm,
      configuration: selectedConfigurationSVM,
      filename: filename
    };
 const predictionAccuracy = document.getElementById('predictionAccuracy');
  fetch('/predict', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      filename: filename,
      parameters: parameters
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const predictedClass = data.predicted_class;
      const malignantProb = data.malignant_probability; 
      const benignProb = data.benign_probability; 
      predictionAccuracy.textContent = ''; 
      const lines = [
        `Predicted class: ${predictedClass}`,
        `Malignant probability: ${malignantProb}`,
        `Benign probability: ${benignProb}`
      ];

      lines.forEach(line => {
        const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
        paragraph.textContent = line;
        predictionAccuracy.appendChild(paragraph);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Prediction request error:', error);
    });
});
```

The model is trained correctly because I was able to get distinct probabilities at one point, but then I do not know what happened because I did not change it. The images are loaded correctly. Extracted features are different for every image. I do not even know what else to try.